# RabbitMq - Docker-compose - How to fix 'Connection refused 127.0.0.1:5672' exception

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rabbitmq, asp.net-core-2.2

I have tried several possible solutions on Stack Overflow but nothing seems to work for me.

I am developing microservices using RabbitMQ. The solution contains multiple projects and runs without any problem, but as soon as I use `docker-compose` option to build the project, Visual Studio throws the following exception:

> RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException ExtendedSocketException: Connection refused 127.0.0.1:5672

In my solution, I have three projects communicating with each other via RabbitMQ.

Below is the code for my YAML file.

**My docker-compose.yaml:**

```
version: '3.4'

services:    
  rabbitmq:
    hostname: webnet
    image: rabbitmq:3.7.2-management
    ports:
      - "15672:15672"
      - "5672:5672"    
    networks:
      - webnet

  sql-server-db:
    container_name: sql-server-db
    image: microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    environment:
      SA_PASSWORD: "customerdbalten@123"
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
    networks:
      - webnet

  myproject.simulation.api:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}myprojectsimulationapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: myproject.Simulation.Api/Dockerfile
    links:
      - rabbitmq
    ports:
      - '5000'
    networks:
      - webnet

  myproject.updateservice.api:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}myprojectupdateserviceapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: myproject.updateservice.Api/Dockerfile
    links:
      - rabbitmq
      - sql-server-db
    ports:
      - '5050'
    networks:
      - webnet

  myproject.web:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}myprojectweb
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: MyProject.Web/Dockerfile
    links:
      - rabbitmq
    ports:
      - '5001'
    networks:
      - webnet

networks:
  webnet:
    driver: bridge
```

**My Docker file:**

My Dockerfile looks like the following:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY 
MyProject.UpdateService.Api/MyProject.UpdateService.Api.csproj MyProject.UpdateService.Api/
COPY MyProject.Common/MyProject.Common.csproj MyProject.Common/
RUN dotnet restore MyProject.UpdateService.Api/MyProject.UpdateService.Api.csproj
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/MyProject.UpdateService.Api
RUN dotnet build MyProject.UpdateService.Api.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish MyProject.UpdateService.Api.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyProject.UpdateService.Api.dll"]
```

I've also created another simple solution with nothing but two projects - a sender and receiver - that uses RabbitMQ. This solution throws the same exception while `docker-compose`ing, otherwise, it just runs. The YAML file has nothing but auto-generated code.

Comment: you need to update your connection string in your application, it should not point to `127.0.0.1:5672`, it should be `rabbitmq:5672`. keep in mind `localhost` in contain mean this container, not rabbitmq container. better to show your connections tring.

Comment: in service with in this `docker-compose` if want to connect with rabbitmq it should be like `rabbitmq:5672`, remember in service to service communication you must use service name or container name to connect.

Comment: Your question is quite confusing.

Comment: Thanks, @Adii! Firstly, I'm not using `127.0.0.1:5672` anywhere in the code, so in which file exactly do I need to use `rabbitmq:5672' instead of the `127.0.0.1:5672`? Secondly, I'm simply reading the following credentials from appsettings.json file: Hostname: localhost,  username: guest, password: guest, in the receiver application. Is this the connection string that you are referring to or are you referring to some other connection string?

Comment: Yes exactly, you've to use `rabbitmq:5672` instead of the `127.0.0.1:5672`. Yes these pls update `appsettings.json file: Hostname: rabbitmq:5672`

Comment: Hi, @daudnadeem! Actually, I'm very new to Dockerization, so there are good chances that my question might not make a complete sense because I'm also not sure if I'm creating the docker the right way. So could you please let me know what part of the question is not clear so that I can explain it to you?

Comment: @Adiii In my appsettings.json file, I have changed the HostName from localhost to rabbitmq:5672 in both receiver and sender applications. Now, the error message has changed to `No such device or address`.

Comment: What do you mean by sender and receiver? Any application which need to connect with rabbitmq should use `rabbitmq` as a host if they are part of same docker compose

Comment: @Adiii By sender and receiver, I mean that I have two projects in the same solution and they are using the same docker-compose.yaml file. In one project - the sender application - I'm publishing messages to rabbitMq and the other project - the receiver application - is listening to the message queue. I have changed the hostname to `rabbitmq:5672` in both the applications and now it is showing `No such device or address` exception on line `_connectionFactory.CreateConnection();` This solution runs fine without docker compose.

Comment: @UsmanKhan: re your edit, please do not add names of software in code formatting. RabbitMQ is just a proper noun (with camel-case formatting) - it is not itself code. Adding code formatting in this way just gives editors more work to do.

Comment: @UsmanKhan: apologies, I had forgotten [that I had asked you the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58832937/different-os-server-transferring-files-is-not-working-on-aws-s3-bucket-it-works) a few days ago.

Comment: @halfer, no problem dear. I corrected my self already that time. Thanks for reminding me again.\

Answer (score 5):

From the discussion, we found out that the rabbitMQ container is not running as there is already running rabbitMQ service on the host.

You have two option, stop the host RabbitMQ service and then try to connect with rabbitMQ container.

```
Hostname: rabbitmq:5672
```

Or if you want to connect with Host RabbitMQ service then you can use

```
Hostname: host.docker.internal
#or
Hostname: HOST_IP
```

**I WANT TO CONNECT FROM A CONTAINER TO A SERVICE ON THE HOST**

> The host has a changing IP address (or none if you have no network
>   access). From 18.03 onwards our recommendation is to connect to the
>   special DNS name `host.docker.internal, which resolves to the internal
>   IP address used by the host. This is for development purpose and will
>   not work in a production environment outside of Docker Desktop for
>   Windows.

The gateway is also reachable as `gateway.docker.internal.`

[docker-for-windows-networking](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/networking/)