# Different OS Server transferring files is not working on AWS S3 Bucket, It works only if windows to windows

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have problem setting up my AWS S3 bucket, the server already running on both two server Linux and Windows. The first the that I do to test if the transferring files is correct. I used the Windows to Windows transfer. the function of my codes is working, then second test Linux to Windows. Right now the transferring is not working. I don't know why its not working, if there is configuration need to do in Linux.

I will share to youthe sample code that I made on laravel.

```
exec('aws s3 cp s3://compexp/11-11-2019/'01150exp.zip'  \\\\'xxx.xxx.xx'/c/kitpos/update');
```

When I tried to my Linux AWS terminal it shows look like this:

[image: aws terminal linux]

Comment: might be because of the way `\` for being treated differently in `windows` and `linux` and are you using `/c/` in linux as well ?

Comment: hi @error404 what is the best way to do for that? i can't find any thread for this.

Comment: @UsmanKhan: please do not add random backtick formatting to words. It's not correct, it should not have been approved, and it is less readable in that style. This formatting style is exclusively for small code snippets and console IO, i.e. things that you would type. The words you have highlighted are just proper nouns, so all you need to do is to correct the case. Thanks!

Comment: @halfer thanks for your suggestion. I will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You can Copy files only to local storage, so you need to mount external Windows storage, as a folder to your Linux-filesystem. And only after that copy file.

You can read how to mount Windows folder to Linux here - https://www.poftut.com/how-to-mount-nfs-share-in-linux-and-windows/

But I think this is a bad practice. Why can't you pull files directly from Windows?